# Relationship between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I having difficulties with the @seller_profile.save statement. Why is it not saving?

```
def create 
    @seller_profile = SellerProfile.new(seller_profile_params)
    
    @seller_profile.seller = current_seller
    
    if @seller_profile.save 
     redirect_to home_index_path
    else
      puts "Error"
    end
  end
```

```
 def current_seller 
    @current_seller ||= Seller.find(session[:seller_id]) if session[:seller_id]
    
  end
```

Comment: check the errors with @seller_profile.errors

Comment: `puts` in a controller is really pointless, that doesn't go anywhere. You need to `render` something instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Hanlde your else part with Proper error condition handling
Simple Put will not do the Job

There are following options to handle it

1st by ony Render the JSON

```
   if @seller_profile.save 
     redirect_to home_index_path
   else
     render json: @seller_profile.errors.to_json.to_json
   end
```

2nd redirect back  with error in notification

```
   if @seller_profile.save 
     redirect_to home_index_path
   else
     flash[:error] = @restaurant.errors
     redirect_to :back 
   end
```

3rd Option to use both Option of Render and Redirect at Same Time

```
   if @seller_profile.save 
     redirect_to home_index_path
   else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back , flash[:error] = @restaurant.errors }
      format.json { render json: @seller_profile.errors.to_json.to_json }
    end
   end
```